# How to fill a dataframe using replicate()

Tags: r

I have a list as follows:

```
structure(list(x = "Male          ", x = "Female        ", x = "Unknown       ", 
    x = "Indeterminate"), .Names = c("x", "x", "x", "x"))
```

I also have created a dataframe

```
OGDProcedure<-data.frame(nrow=10)
```

I would like to sample from the list to add to a new column in the dataframe

I tried:

```
OGDProcedureType$Gender<-replicate(10,paste("Gender: ",sample(GeneralGenderType,1)))
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Gender, value = c("Gender:  Male          ",  : replacement has 10 rows, data has 1
```

Do I have to loop this?

Comment: Does this work? `OGDProcedure <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 1))`
You didn't define correctly the data.frame

Comment: Oh OK. Please post as answer even if the question was not that sharp :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OGDProcedure <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 1))
OGDProcedureType$Gender<-replicate(10,paste("Gender: ",sample(GeneralGenderType,1)))
```